# Two different averages on a Tableau graph - user and company-wide in as a reference line

Tags: average, tableau-api, dashboard

I'm using Tableau to show items resolved over time, either 'On Time' or 'Overdue'.

I want to be able to show the users individual performance as a reference line **and** what the company average is as a second reference line.

The graph plots the items 'On Time' over time.

I can only get the users average individual performance to show as a reference line.

Any ideas how to create this company wide average?

Cant share workbook as has sensitive data, but can share calculations.

Comment: Please do share the calculations and a screenshot of what your current graph looks like including any dimensions you are using.  If you have sensitive data, it can help to provide just a mockup of 'faked' values.

Comment: Have you tried doing a dual axis:
1. on time with users dimension placed on colors shelf
2. only on time without users split

make sure to select synchronize axes as initial values might be bit offset.